Definition of homology group as quotient in chain complex
I am working through some theory about abelian categories and complexes from "An Introduction to Homological Algebra" by Rotman. I don't understand one of the sections which I will explain now:
Let
$$ \longrightarrow C_{n+1} \overset{d_{n+1}}{\longrightarrow} C_n \overset{d_n}{\longrightarrow}C_{n-1} \longrightarrow$$
be a complex in an abelian category. We define the homology group
$$H_n(C_{\bullet}):= \mathrm{Ker}d_n / \mathrm{Im}d_{n+1}$$
As far as I know, quotients of this form have only been defined if we have a monomorphism
$$\iota:\mathrm{Im}d_{n+1} \hookrightarrow \mathrm{Ker}d_n$$
and then we can define
$$\mathrm{Ker}d_n / \mathrm{Im}d_{n+1} := \mathrm{Coker}(\iota)$$
Rotman addresses this, but I cannot follow. He says that we have the following commuting (a bit weird because of AMScd) diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathrm{Im}d_{n+1} @= \mathrm{Im}d_{n+1} @= \mathrm{Im}d_{n+1}\\
@V{\exists}VV @V{j}VV @V{0}VV \\
\mathrm{Ker}d_n @>{i}>> C_n @>{d_n}>> C_{n-1}
\end{CD}$$
I think I could figure out why we have that diagram, especially the existence of the morphism $\mathrm{Im}d_{n+1} \to \mathrm{Ker}d_n$. But I could not figure out why this is a monomorphism. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that $i$ and $j$ are monomorphisms.
I would also appreciate a reference where this, i.e. quotients etc., is explained in more detail.

Do you at least understand why it's a monomorphism in a category of modules? When in doubt with abelian categories it's a good idea to start with that case first.

I recall already having the relation $d^2 = 0$ at this point, i.e., $\mathrm{Im}(d_{n+1}) \subset \mathrm{ker}(d_n)$.  So the image of $d_{n+1}$ is the image of a quotient of $C_{n+1}$ in $C_n$ and that image is a subobject of $\mathrm{ker}d_n$...

@QiaochuYuan Yes, I do. But I could not generalize this to an arbitrary abelian category. Or can one show it for the category of abelian groups and then use the metatheorem to apply it to the abelian category?

@EricTowers I cannot follow. What you have written is too dense. For example does "quotient" mean a quotient object or an object of the form $A/B$, which might coincide but I don't know yet. And then what is the image of a quotient?

Ok, so the answer was pretty obvious. And indeed the morphism $\mathrm{Im}d_{n+1} \to \mathrm{Ker}d_n$, let it denote by $\theta$, is a monomorphism because $i$ and $j$ are monomorphisms and $i\theta = j$. For that let $f,g$ be morphisms such that
$$\theta f = \theta g$$
Then we simply have
$$j f = i \theta f = i \theta g = j g$$
But since $j$ is a monomorphism, we have the wanted result
$$f=g$$
